# How to utilize 100% of GPU memory with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 32Gb graphics card and upon start of my script I see:

```
2019-07-11 01:26:19.985367: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 95.16G (102174818304 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2019-07-11 01:26:19.988090: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 85.64G (91957338112 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2019-07-11 01:26:19.990806: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 77.08G (82761605120 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2019-07-11 01:26:19.993527: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 69.37G (74485440512 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2019-07-11 01:26:19.996219: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 62.43G (67036893184 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2019-07-11 01:26:19.998911: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 56.19G (60333203456 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2019-07-11 01:26:20.001601: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 50.57G (54299881472 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2019-07-11 01:26:20.004296: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 45.51G (48869892096 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2019-07-11 01:26:20.006981: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 40.96G (43982901248 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2019-07-11 01:26:20.009660: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 36.87G (39584608256 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2019-07-11 01:26:20.012341: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 33.18G (35626147840 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

After which TF settles with using 96% of my memory. And later, when it runs out of memory it tries to allocate 65G

```
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 65.30G (70111285248 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

My question is, what about remaining 1300MB (0.04*32480)? I would not mind using those before running OOM.

How can I make TF utilize 99.9% of **memory** instead of 96%?

**Update:** nvidia-smi output

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.40.04    Driver Version: 418.40.04    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:16.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   66C    P0   293W / 300W |  31274MiB / 32480MiB |    100%      Default |
```

I am asking about these 1205MB (31274MiB - 32480MiB) remaining unused. Maybe they are there for a reason, maybe they are used just before OOM.

Answer (score 7):

Monitoring GPU is not as simple as monitoring CPU.
There are many parallel processes going on which could create a `bottleneck` for your GPU.

There could be various problems like :
1. Read/Write speed for your data
2. Either CPU or disk is causing a bottleneck

But I think it is pretty normal to use 96%. Not to mention nvidia-smi only shows for one specific instance.

You can install `gpustat`  and use it to monitor GPU live(you should be hitting 100% during OOM)

```
pip install gpustat

gpustat -i
```

What can you do ?
1. You can use [data_iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/make_initializable_iterator) to process the data in parallel faster.
2. Increase batch size. (I dont think this will work in your case as you are hitting `OOM`)
3. You can overclock the GPU(not-recommended)

[Here](https://www.imgtec.com/blog/a-quick-guide-to-writing-opencl-kernels-for-rogue/) is a nice article for hardware accelaration.

Answer (score 0):

I get about this same utilization rate when I train models using Tensorflow. The reason is pretty clear in my case, I'm manually choosing a random batch of samples and calling the optimization for each batch separately.

That means that each batch of data is in main memory, it's then copied into GPU memory where the rest of the model is, then forward/back propagation and update is performed in-gpu, then execution is handed back to my code where I grab another batch and call optimize on it.

There's a faster way to do that if you spend a few hours setting up Tensorflow to do batch loading in parallel from pre-prepared TF records.

I realize you may or may not be using tensorflow under keras, but since my experience tends to produce very similar utilization numbers, I'm going out on a limb by suggesting that there's a reasonably likely causal link to draw from these correlations. If your framework is loading each batch from main memory into the GPU without the added efficiency/complexity of asynchronous loading (which the GPU itself can handle), then this would be an expected result.

Comment: My question is rather about memory usage in particular. I want to have all 100% of memory to be used before running OOM

Comment: Then do make tweaks with your batch size.